# Laravel with Pusher simply doenst listen to events

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

What am i missing? I did everything right but when i sent a new Event my console just doesnt log anything, here is my code:

**FRONT END**

I imported the required libraries:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = Echo;

window.pusherEcho = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'my-key',
    cluster: 'us2',
    forceTLS: true,
    wsHost: window.location.host,
    wsPort: 8000
});
```

**BACK END**

My event class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

// ... imports

class ReceivedNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('received-notification');
    }
}
```

I registered a route just to test it:

```php
Route::get('/event', function() {
    event(new App\Events\ReceivedNotification('Hello world'));

    return 'event sent';
});
```

**FRONT END**

I'm listening to events in some page with Laravel Echo:

```js
pusherEcho.channel('received-notification')
    .listen('ReceivedNotification', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
});
```

When i go to the route `/event` it never triggers the `console.log` above, which means something is just wrong, yes my `.env` file is everything ok i already checked:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
. 
.
.
PUSHER_APP_ID=***
PUSHER_APP_KEY=***
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=***
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can see you are creating private channel in App\Events\ReceivedNotification and listen public channel in front-end.
So change your front-end to below code :

```
pusherEcho.private('received-notification')
    .listen('ReceivedNotification', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
});
```

Also register your Event and Listerner in app\Providers\EventServiceProvider like :

```
protected $listen = [
   'App\Events\ReceivedNotification' => [
            'App\Listeners\ReceivedNotificationListener'
        ],
]
```

Comment: You'r right, although that was not the only thing i missed, your answer give me the first hint to solve my problem. After that i had to uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php` and register my channel to allow in the routes in `routes/channels.php`, after that everything worked ok.

Comment: Its necessary to deal with csrf token too for requests, so here is a complete and more detaild tutorial for those who need it: https://christoph-rumpel.com/2020/11/laravel-real-time-notifications